# Не могу получить доступ к тестовому API

Tags: javascript, fetch, cors

Есть сайт на хостинге, к которому нужно подключить платежную систему. К API платежной системы есть документация:

> URL адрес тестового eCommerce хоста, на который необходимо отправлять
> запросы:
>
> https://test3ds.bcc.kz:5445/cgi-bin/cgi_link
>
> Хост всегда доступен, отдельных доступов запрашивать не нужно.

Однако мне не удается отправить POST-запрос через js к этому ресурсу. Ошибка:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://test3ds.bcc.kz:5445/cgi-bin/cgi_link' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

*(с самого сайта тоже не получается получить доступ)*

Причем с помощью онлайн ресурсов (https://reqbin.com/post-online) все получается, доступ к серверу осуществляется, ответ приходит верный. На данном ресурсе заголовки и тело запроса использую те же, что и при отправке запроса с помощью js.
Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Возможный дубликат [уже существующих семидесяти двух вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+CORS+isanswered%3A1) о том же самом :)

Comment: Добрый вечер! Я бы не сказал, что о том, же самом. У меня же нет доступа к серверу, к которому я обращаюсь, не я его писал. Поэтому я не смогу прописать там необходимые заголовки. Наверно стоит обратиться к разработчикам этого API? Или я все-таки что-то где-то упустил?

Comment: Ладно, представим что проблема и правда уникальна, и разберем ее случай - с какого ориджина фактически выполняется AJAX-запрос?

Comment: @yar85, https://ipotekavsem.kz

Comment: Ну вот, это типичный кроссдоменный запрос (`ipotekavsem.kz != test3ds.bcc.kz:5445`), так что же здесь делает проблему уникальной? В тексте ошибки говорится что целевой эндпоинт не разрешает кроссдоменные запросы (либо ресурс их разрешает но делаешь что-то не так, например не на тот URL шлешь запрос - либо ресурс не разрешает и это ожидаемое поведение).

Comment: Агрегаторы и подобные сервисы могут специально не разрешать кроссдоменные AJAX, просто для того чтобы защитить нерадивых клиентов от самих себя (чтобы те отправляли запросы безопасно, со своих серверов - а не со страничек, открывая XSS уязвимости). В документации вебAPI должно быть четко указано, как надо обращаться к нему. Если же в доках такого не указано (крайне редко такое бывает), то этот момент все равно можно прояснить: обратившись в службу поддержки клиентов того сервиса. А чисто технически - тут все правильно работает, и никакой проблемы не просматривается.

Comment: Надо понимать что CORS это политика для юзерагента (браузера, например). Она внедрена и существует не во вред, а для повышения безопасности передачи данных в интернете. Поэтому, очень плохой идеей будет пытаться обойти ее - гораздо лучше последовать верному пути, передавая все чувствительные данные безопасно (типичная схема взаимодействия: страница с CSP шлет запрос на свой же бэкэнд с CORS, и далее этот бэкэнд делает запросы к эндпоинтам внешнего сервиса, также защищенным CORS... так, в собственных скриптах все работает, а посторонние злые скрипты в этот процесс "влезть" так просто не могут).

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно прописать соответствующий заголовок на своём сервере. Вот тут подробно об этом: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Comment: И как же это сделать, если нет доступа к серверу?)

Comment: @Платон, так... "есть сайт на хостинге..." Чей сайт? Не Ваш? У вас к нему доступа нет? Вы совершаете запрос с клиентской стороны... Окей. А как Вы получили возможность его оттуда совершать? Вероятно потому что это Ваш сайт на хостинге... Проясните ситуацию.

Comment: заголовки, о которых ведется речь в статье, которую вы скинули, прописываются на сервере К которому происходит обращение сетевого запроса. К этому серверу доступа у меня нет, это сервер платежной системы. А к своему сайту, ОТКУДА я выполняю запрос, у меня доступ есть. @Иван

Comment: @Платон тогда делайте запрос не с клиента с сервера своего. Сначала делаете запрос на свой сервер оттуда к API. потом давайте ответ клиенту

Comment: Действительно, так получилось отправить запрос. А почему это происходит? С фронта запрос не удается совершить, а с сервера все работает? Это мой косяк, косяк разработчиков API, или вообще так и должно быть? @Иван

Comment: @Платон, это не Ваш косяк и не косяк разработчиков API. Это методы безопасности. https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch-crossorigin